# Non-commutative analogue of a certain fact in differential geometry

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, curvature

In the literature, is there a non-commutative analogue of the fact that every Riemannian manifold whose isometry group has sharp dimension must be a constant curvature manifold?

Comment: What do you mean by "sharp dimension"? Do you mean that  $M$ is $n$-dimensional and $dim(Isom(M,g))=n(n+1)/2$? Such manifolds need not be flat, they are manifolds of constant curvature.

Comment: I mean so. Tes you are right I revise the question

Comment: @MoisheKohan thanks for your helpful comment.